# Восстановление ViewPager после уничтожения приложения

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Activity содержит ViewPager с несколькими вкладками, заполняемыми фрагментами. Когда система выгружает приложение из памяти из-за нехватки ресурсов, при восстановлении приложения, восстанавливается та же самая Activity, к ней прикрепляются экземпляры фрагментов существовашие в момент уничтожения. При этом в Activity.onCreate содержится стандартная логика создания и заполнения ViewPager фрагментами:

```
ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ProjectActivity.this);
for (ProjectData projectData : projectData) {
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(ProjectFragment.newInstance(projectData));
}
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

В итоге Activity содержит ссылки на вновь созданные экземпляры фрагментов, а прикреплены к ней старые (восстановленные) экземпляры фрагментов.  В данный момент принято решение - при старте Activity проверка пустой ли стек фрагментов, если нет - удаление существующих фрагментов, и стандартное заполнение адаптера новыми экземплярами фрагментов:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
List<Fragment> oldFragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
if (!oldFragments.isEmpty()) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for (Fragment fragment: oldFragments) {
        transaction.remove(fragment);
    }
    transaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
for (ProjectData projectData : projectData) {
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(ProjectFragment.newInstance(projectData));
}
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

Подозреваю что это не верное решение, а как стандартно решить этот вопрос?
Также не понимаю почему при вызове `viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)`  новые экземпляры фрагментов загруженные в адаптер не проходят свой жизненный цикл пока не очистишь стек фрагментов.

Comment: фрагменты нужно не самому создавать и передавать в адаптер, а они должны создаваться только в методе адаптера, (в getItem для адаптера ViewPager, createFragment для адаптера ViewPager2). ViwePager проверяет фрагменты в FragmentManager и вызывает метод создания только если их там нет

Comment: Пытаюсь понять это решение. Есть ситуация когда количество создаваемых фрагментов зависит от данных приходящих по подписке LiveData, то есть от "бизнес-логики". Правильно ли будет переносить эту логику в адаптер?

Comment: передавайте модель данных в адаптер, а уже на её основе создавайте нужный фрагмент в методе адаптера

Comment: Да, в таком варианте фрагменты восстанавливаются корректно. Но возникла проблема с тем, что когда приходят новые данные, то адаптер размещает фрагмент с новой моделью в крайнюю правую вкладку таба (что соответствует последней существующей position +1). А по дизайну приложения требуется разместить новый фрагмент в крайную левую вкладку (что соответствует position = 0). И так понимаю, этого можно добиться только как-то сортируя стек фрагментов. Есть ли стандартные решения в данном случае? Документация не описывает такой случай.  IR42 - случайно "42" это не Кемеровский регион? )